# Start 2 commands, wait for the end of the second command, then kill the first command

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to create a .sh script that does the following:

- Start a first command `./first.sh`
- Start a second command `./second.sh`
- Wait for the end of the second command
- Kill the first command
- End of the script

I know how to start a command and i know how to start a command without blocking the script. But i don't know how to kill the first command with the second one is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

./first.sh &
firstpid="$!"

./second.sh

kill "$firstpid"
```